# "Queuing" for Powerautomate flow reduction?

Tags: power-automate

I am a low-credentialled creator at my institution (i.e. not a sysadmin with access to Azure VM execution, on a per-owner licenced non-premium account) and am developing a simple but intricate Sharepoint list-based app to allow group members to book appointments in predetermined blocks.  As a nod to the local office team, who want to keep using their existing dashboard system, I am also trying to "synchronize" their Excel workbook (with a table of 750 rows x 15 columns) with my list structure (smaller but comparable) using PowerAutomate, so that support staff can continue to input, modify and report in Excel while users are booking through the app.

I'm aware synchronization is a frustrating task, especially given that essentially I have to loop through the entire excel table to evaluate if anything needs updating (if anyone has a good shortcut for this, please let me know!), but I think I've found a scheme which gives them basically what they want by reducing how much of the workbook needs to be updated live. I can use a partial "quick sync" as a flow triggering when sharepoint detects the file has been modified, and set up a scheduled overnight "full sync" to bring all the data up to speed.  By taking the lookup work out of the core table row loop and using some parallel execution I've gotten the runtime of this "quick sync" flow down to a manageable 2-3 minutes.

However, it seems disruptive to run the sync loop *every* time the workbook file is modified. If folks are editing workbooks directly in Teams or Excel 365, it seems reasonable that there may be multiple edits within that window of time, and it might cause problems both server and client-side to continuously loop sync jobs while the file is being edited.  I could use some message passing to skip those edits prompted by my list flows changing the workbook, but that wouldn't address the "live editing" use case.

So I had a couple of thoughts about how I might reduce the amount of work being done by this flow using a hidden sharepoint list.  Option 1 is to run a scheduled daemon job, which checks every half hour and executes once if it sees a flag set by a sharepoint file modified trigger.  Option 2 is to set up a kind of Buffer queue structure as a sharepoint list, where we record jobs as they come in, use Delay components to wait some time, and then only run if we're the last job in the queue.

I think I can implement either of these options, though they're definitely a hacky solution to the problem, so can I ask if I'm reinventing the wheel?  Are there other ways within the PowerAutomate platform or Sharepoint folder modify connector to reduce redundant flow triggers, or is there a more effective form of Excel listener that might simplify the problem?

I'd be grateful for any tips you might have!